# It is correct to say that a tensor is simply a multidimensional array of related quantities? But what about a tensor as a transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra

It is correct to say that a tensor is simply a multidimensional array of **related** quantities?

More specifically a tensor is a **collection** or **tuples** of vectors where every vector in the tuple represent a different type of information but the components of the different vectors depend of each other.

I said this because of the following sentence I read in Wikipedia:

"at the end of the 19th century, the electromagnetic field was understood as a collection of two vector fields in space. nowadays, one recognizes this as a single antisymmetric 2nd-rank tensor field in spacetime"

I understand that electric and magnetic fields are grouped into a tensor because the components the magnetic field depend of some maner of the components of the electric field and viceversa.

But what about tensors as **transformation** objects? if you have two vectors (not tuples of vectors) then the transformation is simply a matrix (or rank 2 tensor), but what is the necessity for tensors of rank bigger than 2? Is to transform tuples of vectors?

I only have a background in physics so please try to answer in the most simple terms.

Comment: Be aware that the term tensor is used on data analysis and machine learning for a multidimensional array without the transformation properties that's mathematical physics tensor has.

Comment: rank one tensors are vectors and linear functionals (covectors). Rank two tensors are tensor products of rank one tensors... and so on

Comment: Hi janmarqz, and what is the practical need (in physics, engineering, etc) of having  tensors of rank bigger than 2?

Comment: Can you say that as a matrix resulting from the tensor product of two vectors is the relation between this 2 vectors, a tensor of rank 3 is the object that defines the relation between two matrices or rank 2 tensors?

Comment: with a tensor of rank four you can describe curvature of space-times, do special and general relativity, classify solutions of several Einstein Field Eqns, build physical theories on multiple dimensions..., among a plethora of phenomena. For the 1st question.

Comment: for the second: if you tensor-product of basic one you build basic-rank-two-tensors  to write all rank two tensor as a linear combinations. And a rank three tensor uses one tensor of rank two and  one tensor of rank one, also thru the tensor product.

Answer (score 1):

A tensor is a "multidimensional array of quantities" in the same sense that a vector is an "array of quantities" -- that is, you're giving a description of the *coordinate representation* of said objects relative to a chosen basis.

The example of electromagnetism is just an example of a phenomenon where, when we move to a unified notion of space-time, that some classical quantities turn out to be the time and space components of some other quantity. Another example is how energy and classical 3-dimensional momentum turn out to be the time and space components of the special relativity momentum 4-vector

There is a rank 2 tensor field which breaks apart into components:

- The (time, time) component is zero
- The (time, space) component is the electric field vector
- The (space, time) component is the negative of the electric field vector
- The (space, space) component is the magnetic field pseudovector

(in coordinates, the magnetic field really ought to be an antisymmetric two-dimensional array of scalars — but as history goes we first discovered how to represent such things via pseudovector, and that description has stuck in classical physics)

Comment: I'd add that it's like saying "a linear transformation is just a matrix".

Answer (score 0):

It's more common to refer to transformation properties:

A tensor of rank $(p, q),$ i.e. with $p$ upper indices and $q$ lower indices, on an $n$-dimensional space, is an object with $n^{pq}$ components, which transform using $p$ factors of $J$ and $q$ factors of $J^{-1},$ each acting on a different index, where $J = \partial x_{\text{new}} / \partial x_{\text{old}}$ is the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the coordinate change.